# "to" as a word before an infinitive or as a preposition

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive

In a dictionary, I find two example sentences of the use of "trick":

> What's the **trick to** getting this chair to fold up?
>
> On page 21, some **tricks to** speed up your beauty routine.

As we know, "**to**" can use be used as a preposition or as a word before an infinitive. When do we use it as a preposition and when as a word before an infinitive?

Comment: This site helps to answer your question: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/to

Comment: Yes, it helps, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: When the word "trick" can be followed by both "to-infinitive" and "to+ noun" (to as a preposition), what is the difference?

Comment: Why don't you respond to my answer? It actually answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

idiom: a trick to [**gerund**]. A gerund functions as noun, not a verb. To is a preposition.

- The trick to **getting better grades** is to study more.

The test is: getting better grades.

Can "getting better grades" be used as a noun phrase?
Answer: Yes, it can.

- Getting better grades is not always easy.

Another test: What is the trick to this?
"To this" is not a to-infinitive. Therefore, it's a preposition.

A trick to speed up your beauty routine. to **speed up** is a verb. And to speed up is a to-infinitive.

Summary: a trick to [gerund as noun] versus a trick to [verb]

Answer (score -2):

All prepositions are followed by ing forms including the preposition to.

1.I am interested in learning English.

2.I am looking forward to seeing you.

The problem with the preposition to is itsometimes becomes the part of a infinitive
For examle, I want to meet you
He wishes to meet her
so the trick is if to is a preposition,it follows an ing form otherwise it is followed by an infinitive like go,meet and talk

Comment: no, you don't answer my question.

Comment: My question is: when the word "trick" can be followed by both "to-infinitive" and "to+ noun" (to as a preposition), what is the difference?